# Face landmark detection using Mediapipe and in C++

Tags: c++, mediapipe, face-landmark

In may 2023, the mediaipie team released a new API which makes it easy to extract face landmarks from videos and live streams in [python and Javascript](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/face_landmarker), which have very clear code examples. This API uses the new [tasks](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/tasks) to run the updated [FaceMeshV2](https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-assets/Model%20Card%20MediaPipe%20Face%20Mesh%20V2.pdf) model. All of this is working well on python and javascript.

I would like to use these models but in C++. Specifically, I would like to run the model [FaceMeshV2](https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-assets/Model%20Card%20MediaPipe%20Face%20Mesh%20V2.pdf). But it seems that there is no  documentation on how to do this in C++. However, in the code, it seems that python uses the C bindings to do this, using e.g. [face_landmarker.h](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/tasks/cc/vision/face_landmarker/face_landmarker.h) or [face_landlmarker.cc](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/tasks/cc/vision/face_landmarker/face_landmarker.cc).

Does anyone know where I can find clear documentation of how this works on C++? Is there already an open-source project that extracts landmarks with mediapipe in C++? Alternatively, is there an open-source project that runs a mediapipe task in C++? Any info or tutorial on compiling/running mediapipe tasks with the updated API in C++ would be of great help!

Comment: But Google Mediapipe is fully open source: https://github.com/google/mediapipe with C++ example applications and stuff.

Comment: Hi! Where did you see the C++ example application?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/hello_world_cpp.md

Comment: Yes, I know that resource, but the documentation is not very clear, and its use is complex and not taylored for the extraction of landmarks, so I'm looking for a more specific C++ resource to extract landmarks using mediapipe. If someone has one, that would be very helpful.